# Solve n-puzzle in Java

Tags: java, search, artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm, sliding-tile-puzzle

I'm trying to implement a program to solve the [n-puzzle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteen_puzzle). 
I have written a simple implementation in Java that has a state of the problem characterized by a matrix representing the tiles. I am also able to auto-generate the graph of all the states giving the starting state. On the graph, then, I can do a BFS to find the path to the goal state.
But the problem is that I run out of memory and I cannot even create the whole graph.
I tried with a 2x2 tiles and it works. Also with some 3x3 (it depends on the starting state and how many nodes are in the graph). But in general this way is not suitable.
So I tried generating the nodes at runtime, while searching. It works, but it is slow (sometimes after some minutes it still have not ended and I terminate the program).
Btw: I give as starting state only solvable configurations and I don't create duplicated states.
So, I cannot create the graph. This leads to my main problem: I have to implement the A* algorithm and I need the path cost (i.e. for each node the distance from the starting state), but I think I cannot calculate it at runtime. I need the whole graph, right? Because A* does not follow a BFS exploration of the graph, so I don't know how to estimate the distance for each node. Hence, I don't know how to perform an A* search.
Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

`State:`

```
private int[][] tiles;
private int pathDistance;
private int misplacedTiles;
private State parent;

public State(int[][] tiles) {
    this.tiles = tiles;
    pathDistance = 0;
    misplacedTiles = estimateHammingDistance();
    parent = null;
}

public ArrayList<State> findNext() {
    ArrayList<State> next = new ArrayList<State>();
    int[] coordZero = findCoordinates(0);
    int[][] copy;
    if(coordZero[1] + 1 < Solver.SIZE) {
        copy = copyTiles();
        int[] newCoord = {coordZero[0], coordZero[1] + 1};
        switchValues(copy, coordZero, newCoord);
        State newState = checkNewState(copy);
        if(newState != null)
            next.add(newState);
    }
    if(coordZero[1] - 1 >= 0) {
        copy = copyTiles();
        int[] newCoord = {coordZero[0], coordZero[1] - 1};
        switchValues(copy, coordZero, newCoord);
        State newState = checkNewState(copy);
        if(newState != null)
            next.add(newState);
    }
    if(coordZero[0] + 1 < Solver.SIZE) {
        copy = copyTiles();
        int[] newCoord = {coordZero[0] + 1, coordZero[1]};
        switchValues(copy, coordZero, newCoord);
        State newState = checkNewState(copy);
        if(newState != null)
            next.add(newState);
    }
    if(coordZero[0] - 1 >= 0) {
        copy = copyTiles();
        int[] newCoord = {coordZero[0] - 1, coordZero[1]};
        switchValues(copy, coordZero, newCoord);
        State newState = checkNewState(copy);
        if(newState != null)
            next.add(newState);
    }
    return next;
}

private State checkNewState(int[][] tiles) {
    State newState = new State(tiles);
    for(State s : Solver.states)
        if(s.equals(newState))
            return null;
    return newState;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(this == null || obj == null)
        return false;
    if (obj.getClass().equals(this.getClass())) {
        for(int r = 0; r < tiles.length; r++) { 
            for(int c = 0; c < tiles[r].length; c++) {
                if (((State)obj).getTiles()[r][c] != tiles[r][c])
                    return false;
            }
        }
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

`Solver:`

```
public static final HashSet<State> states = new HashSet<State>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    solve(new State(selectStartingBoard()));
}

public static State solve(State initialState) {
    TreeSet<State> queue = new TreeSet<State>(new Comparator1());
    queue.add(initialState);
    states.add(initialState);
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
        State current = queue.pollFirst();
        for(State s : current.findNext()) {
            if(s.goalCheck()) {
                s.setParent(current);
                return s;
            }
            if(!states.contains(s)) {
                s.setPathDistance(current.getPathDistance() + 1);
                s.setParent(current);
                states.add(s);
                queue.add(s);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Basically here is what I do:
- `Solver`'s `solve` has a `SortedSet`. Elements (`States`) are sorted according to `Comparator1`, which calculates `f(n) = g(n) + h(n)`, where `g(n)` is the path cost and `h(n)` is a heuristic (the number of misplaced tiles).
- I give the starting configuration and look for all the successors.
- If a successor has not been already visited (i.e. if it is not in the global set `States`) I add it to the queue and to `States`, setting the current state as its parent and `parent's path + 1` as its path cost.
- Dequeue and repeat.

I think it should work because:
- I keep all the visited states so I'm not looping.
- Also, there won't be any useless edge because I immediately store current node's successors. E.g.: if from A I can go to B and C, and from B I could also go to C, there won't be the edge B->C (since path cost is 1 for each edge and A->B is cheaper than A->B->C).
- Each time I choose to expand the path with the minimum `f(n)`, accordin to A*.

But it does not work. Or at least, after a few minutes it still can't find a solution (and I think is a lot of time in this case).

If I try to create a tree structure before executing A*, I run out of memory building it.

**EDIT 2**
Here are my heuristic functions:

```
private int estimateManhattanDistance() {
    int counter = 0;
    int[] expectedCoord = new int[2];
    int[] realCoord = new int[2];
    for(int value = 1; value < Solver.SIZE * Solver.SIZE; value++) {
        realCoord = findCoordinates(value);
        expectedCoord[0] = (value - 1) / Solver.SIZE;
        expectedCoord[1] = (value - 1) % Solver.SIZE;
        counter += Math.abs(expectedCoord[0] - realCoord[0]) + Math.abs(expectedCoord[1] - realCoord[1]);
    }
    return counter;
}

private int estimateMisplacedTiles() {
    int counter = 0;
    int expectedTileValue = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < Solver.SIZE; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < Solver.SIZE; j++) {
            if(tiles[i][j] != expectedTileValue)
                if(expectedTileValue != Solver.ZERO)
                    counter++;
            expectedTileValue++;
        }
    return counter;
}
```

If I use a simple greedy algorithm they both work (using Manhattan distance is really quick (around 500 iterations to find a solution), while with number of misplaced tiles it takes around 10k iterations). If I use A* (evaluating also the path cost) it's really slow.

Comparators are like that:

```
public int compare(State o1, State o2) {
    if(o1.getPathDistance() + o1.getManhattanDistance() >= o2.getPathDistance() + o2.getManhattanDistance())
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

**EDIT 3**

There was a little error. I fixed it and now A* works. Or at least, for the 3x3 if finds the optimal solution with only 700 iterations. For the 4x4 it's still too slow. I'll try with IDA*, but one question: how long could it take with A* to find the solution? Minutes? Hours? I left it for 10 minutes and it didn't end.

Comment: Probably this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA* ? It is A* and Depth-limited search - you don't need to store the states that you have visited.

Comment: one thing to say : tl;dr

Comment: @nhahtdh I know IDA*, but I have to use A* (it's for an university assignment). About the storage: at first I need to store them all to create the graph, and here is when I run out of memory. I cannot even run A*!

Comment: @Simon: Not sure, but 9! (actually half of this) is only ~360k. You need to find out a scheme to store the states efficiently (as close as 360k, or if possible 180k). 15 (or 16) puzzle problem (4x4) cannot be solved with pure A*.

Comment: @nhahtdh Are you sure? I looked on Google and it seems that it's possible. Also the assigment I have to do clearly says "implement A* to solve it".
About the storage, I think my representation is really simple and efficent. Maybe there is something wrong, but I don't think so (with a 2x2 board it works). I'll post the code as soon as I can.

Comment: @Simon: 15/16 puzzle has 16!, which is ~2e13 states. You may not have to keep track of all of them, but I'm not sure whether you will run out of memory when keeping track of the states.

Comment: @nhahtdh I'm sure that (by now) I run out of memory because of the number of states. I tried only to create the graph, without solving it, and I can't. About the algorithm: how can I do without tracking the states? How do I know that I'm not going back to a previous state? I added the code, please take a look.

Comment: @Simon: If you don't want to track state, you can look at IDA* (which only has 1 state at a time). If you want to use A*, you need to convert the board state into corresponding permutation number (not sure about the terminology here, but basically if you generate all permutation, then this is the order in which it will be generated), and use a boolean array to keep track whether the permutation has been visited before or not. (This won't help for 16-puzzle, though).

Comment: For 3x3 case, another option is to store first 8 tiles as nibble (by using bit wise operations), and you will end up with an `int` type, which can be put into a Set.

Comment: The point of A* is exactly to find a heuristic that can give an admissible estimate on the distance of two nodes without knowing anything about the other nodes.

Comment: You should retag this as homework.

Comment: How *exactly* is your heuristic defined?

Comment: @Simon: IDA* can solve 4x4 under 1 minute (in C/C++ - Java should be a bit longer, but if coded efficiently should be around that figure). I can be sure, since there is an exact problem on UVa that has time limit of 15 seconds, IIRC.

Comment: @nhahtdh I just tried to implement IDA*, but it didn't improved. As I've seen, my problem now is that I store all visited states and keeping them sorted is really expansive (in time). IDA* doesn't help me for this, because it is just A* but the tree is little by little deeper. But it still keeps track of all visited states. Maybe I'm wrong, but I've found some implementation on the internet working in this way. What should I do to solve my problem (time complexity)?

Comment: @Simon: Just keep searching. Do not store visited state - that is what IDA* is about.

Comment: If your puzzle is one move away from completion, what values do your heuristics return.  What values should they return.  Are they admissible?  Think carefully about that.

Comment: @nhahtdh I must keep all visited states, since I'm using functions admissible but (I think) not consistent. The space is a graph and so the heuristic must be consistent, or the algorithm can loop or be not optimal. That's why I keep all visited nodes (it's also written in the book "AI: A modern approach"). Anyway slows is keeping the queue of nodes to be visited ordered. I tried IDA* but with few results. I created a new question about it [link](http://goo.gl/Q1mMx).

Comment: @Novak My heuristics are all admissible (Manhattan, Hamming, Gaschnig distance, Manhattan distance adjusted with linear conflicts, and so on...).

Comment: Do the calculations, Simon.  What answers are your heuristics giving you when one tile is out of place?  What answers should they give you?

Comment: @Novak I tried them. They all work. Anyway, I fixed the code and now IDA* (with Manhattan and linear conflicts) solves every problem faster. For problems that require 45 moves it takes 10 seconds. For bigger ones (60+ moves) it takes 1 hour. I think it's reasonable.

Comment: Are you doing AI at UQ? rofl. Because I've got nearly the exact same base code

Comment: @Rices Yep :D Actually I saw (only a few days ago) that all I have done (finding deeper solutions) wasn't required by the prof XD

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to generate all state space nodes for solving a problem using BFS, A* or any tree search, you just add states you can explore from current state to the fringe and that's why there is a successor function.
If BFS consumes much memory it is normal. But I don't know exactly fro what n it would make problem. Use DFS instead.
For A* you know how many moves you made to come to current state and you can estimate moves need to solve problem, simply by relaxing problem. As an example you can think that any two tiles can replace and then count moves needed to solve the problem. You heuristic just needs to be admissible ie. your estimate be less then actual moves needed to solve the problem.

Comment: I need to STORE all states to avoid looping. From here, my memory problem. But anyway, all solved already :)

Comment: Not all states, just visited states.

Comment: That are, as I progress creating states, all states. I do not create all states before exploring them. I create them "at runtime", and as I create them, I store them.

Comment: The same. BFS and DFS are slow because they don't use any heuristic. A* is slow because it needs to keep visited states sorted. I solved with IDA*, that use a heuristic and does not need any sorting.

Answer (score 0):

add a path cost to your state class and every time you go from a parent state P to another state like C do this : c.cost = P.cost + 1 this will compute the path cost for every node automatically
this is also a very good and simple implementation in C# for 8-puzzle solver with A* take a look at it you will learn many things : 
http://geekbrothers.org/index.php/categories/computer/12-solve-8-puzzle-with-a

Comment: I'm so sorry I don't know why this happened but I fixed it.